# Delegate must respond to locationManager:didFailWithError: even though implemented didFailWithError method

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, cllocationmanager, didfailwitherror

For some reason Xcode thinks I'm not implementing `didFailWithError` method of the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol

[image]
[image]

I fail to see what I'm doing wrong, as I literally copied from another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40345170/delegate-must-respond-to-locationmanagerdidupdatelocations-swift-eroor) that said this `didFailWithError`method was updated for Swift 3. So I don't understand why Xcode thinks I'm not implementing `didFailWithError`

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

### Code

```
class OptionsViewController: UIViewController,
    CLLocationManagerDelegate {
var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
//Ask user for location
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        
        //Use users current location if no starting point set
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse
                || CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways {
                locationManager.requestLocation()
            }
            else{
                locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            }
        }
        else{
            //Alert user to open location service, bra bra bra here...
        }
    }

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("error:: \(error)")
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        print("didChangeAuthorization")
        if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse
            || status == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways {
            locationManager.requestLocation()
        }
        else{
            //other procedures when location service is not permitted.
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print("Did update location called")
//        let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
//        print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
        if locations.first != nil {
            print("location:: (location)")
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: where is locationManager declared?

Comment: The picture you posted clearly tells you how to fix the problem.

Comment: The code works with the exception of two issues, 1) I don't see any declaration of your `locationManager` var  2) Your missing a final `}` for your class. With those two fixes, it compiles for for me.

Comment: @LeoDabus I was a bit hasty and did not add the declaration by mistake. I've added it now. Please let me know if my declaration is correct

Comment: @rmp I was a bit hasty and did not add the declaration by mistake. I've added it now. Please let me know if my declaration is correct. Also I know I'm definitely not missing `}` in my actual code b/c my code compiles; it's just the `CLLManager` does not work

Comment: @rmaddy could you please copy and past the alternative function header I should type instead of the one I have in the code? I don't see what the difference is between what I have in my code and what Xcode is suggesting I use.

Comment: Did you do what Xcode suggested and make the method `private`?

Comment: @rmaddy Yep didn't do anything. Still got error `Delegate must respond to locationManager:didFailWithError:`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aaaandd I realized it's b/c I needed to use an `Error` of a specific type (specifically `Swift.Error`)
This is the right method declaration for `didFailWithError`:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Swift.Error) {
```

Comment: This was my issue too. In my codebase, someone else had declared an `enum` called Error and it was clashing with the `Swift.Error`.